# How to put a username session variable on a page with an already started session

Tags: php

Ok, so in my code, I have an index.php page with username variable in it that has a username session to call the variable, but it's in the same file that has its own session opened up as well and it plays a role in my website functionality. I'm continually getting these errors on my page,

> Warning**: Undefined variable $username in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\index.php** on line **15
>
> Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\footer.php:1) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\index.php** on line **7
> **

Here is my index.php code:

```
<?php
include_once "safe-header.php";

$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '';

if (empty($username)) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="upload-container">
    <p class="username"><?php echo $username;?></p>
    <div class="account-options">
        <a href="update-profile.php" class="update-profile">Update Profile</a>
        <a href="serverside/logout-server.php" class="logout-btn">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>



<?php
include_once "footer.php";
?>
```

I tried multiple times rephrasing it so I could fit the `$username` variable into my file, but it's not working no matter what I've tried. I'm trying to print the $username that the user set in the login and signup page to the screen.

Comment: Which line is line 15? When I count lines from your code snippet, line 15 is `<head>`. I don't think you're running the code you think you are.

Comment: It seems like some errors are coming from "footer.php" as well. 

Could you also add the code of "safe-header.php" and "footer.php"?

Comment: The "Headers already sent" warning implies that `footer.php` is running *before* the rest of this code. Which doesn't make sense since it's at the end.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()`?

Comment: re headers sent - you can't do a redirect after displaying some html.  The prior error message (undefined $username) counts as displaying html.  Fix the username error, the headers error should disappear.

Comment: @Barmar yes their is a session_start in my index.php and I'm including my safe-header.php file, theirs a session there as well

Comment: @Sarwar Alam, it's just script tags to my script.js and navbar.js files.

Comment: _"headers already sent by (output started at `C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\footer.php:1`) in `C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\index.php` on line 7"_ - so according to this message, you can't do `header("Location: login.php");` in your index.php on line 7, because output was already created before this point, from your _footer.php_ - which must mean, you must have included that one before this line already. (You also said you had a session_start directly in your index.php, which I don't see anywhere in the code you have shown - so we must probably not take most of it at face value to begin with here?)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `session_start()` function? Is it in `safe-header.php`?
You might have an empty line in `safe-header.php` or any kind of headers sent, since your session variable is not set and you get "headers already sent"

Comment: The session variable is in the safe-header.php as well